# Sort array of objects with maximum of total of specific key values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object as follows:

```
var tempListData = [
    {
        "driver": "467f0b0bc9a",
        "company": "9d85ccdcfc5",
        "driverName": "David Smith",
        "companyName": "Express",
        "CreateIdlingEvent": 0,
        "CreateSpeedingEvent": 2502,
        "CreateHarshAccelerationEvent": 1988,
        "CreateHarshDecelerationEvent": 1450
    },
    {
        "driver": "7fcc39deb8fc7",
        "company": "a2345ccdcfc5",
        "driverName": "John Doe",
        "companyName": "Express",
        "CreateSpeedingEvent": 2970,
        "CreateHarshAccelerationEvent": 2414,
        "CreateHarshDecelerationEvent": 1750,
        "CreateIdlingEvent": 0
    },
    {
        "driver": "c4e39006",
        "company": "9d8616dd",
        "driverName": "Henry",
        "companyName": "Express",
        "CreateIdlingEvent": 250,
        "CreateSpeedingEvent": 2300,
        "CreateHarshAccelerationEvent": 1988,
        "CreateHarshDecelerationEvent": 1450
    }
]
```

I need to sort the objects basis on the maximum total of `CreateSpeedingEvent` and `CreateIdlingEvent` and `CreateHarshAccelerationEvent` and `CreateHarshDecelerationEvent` values.

i.e. object with the maximum total values of "CreateIdlingEvent", CreateSpeedingEvent,CreateHarshAccelerationEvent, and CreateHarshDecelerationEvent  that should become the first object in the  array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** You can sort it using customised sorting comparator function

```js
var tempListData = [
  {
    driver: "467f0b0bc9a",
    company: "9d85ccdcfc5",
    driverName: "David Smith",
    companyName: "Express",
    CreateIdlingEvent: 0,
    CreateSpeedingEvent: 2502,
    CreateHarshAccelerationEvent: 1988,
    CreateHarshDecelerationEvent: 1450,
  },
  {
    driver: "7fcc39deb8fc7",
    company: "a2345ccdcfc5",
    driverName: "John Doe",
    companyName: "Express",
    CreateSpeedingEvent: 2970,
    CreateHarshAccelerationEvent: 2414,
    CreateHarshDecelerationEvent: 1750,
    CreateIdlingEvent: 0,
  },
  {
    driver: "c4e39006",
    company: "9d8616dd",
    driverName: "Henry",
    companyName: "Express",
    CreateIdlingEvent: 250,
    CreateSpeedingEvent: 2300,
    CreateHarshAccelerationEvent: 1988,
    CreateHarshDecelerationEvent: 1450,
  },
];

const getSum = (o) =>
  o.CreateIdlingEvent +
  o.CreateSpeedingEvent +
  o.CreateHarshAccelerationEvent +
  o.CreateHarshDecelerationEvent;

const result = [...tempListData].sort((a, b) => getSum(b) - getSum(a));

console.log(result);
```

**2)** You can first create a `map` of sum using [`Map`](http://Map) and then sort it using customised sorting function as:

```js
var tempListData = [
  {
    driver: "467f0b0bc9a",
    company: "9d85ccdcfc5",
    driverName: "David Smith",
    companyName: "Express",
    CreateIdlingEvent: 0,
    CreateSpeedingEvent: 2502,
    CreateHarshAccelerationEvent: 1988,
    CreateHarshDecelerationEvent: 1450,
  },
  {
    driver: "7fcc39deb8fc7",
    company: "a2345ccdcfc5",
    driverName: "John Doe",
    companyName: "Express",
    CreateSpeedingEvent: 2970,
    CreateHarshAccelerationEvent: 2414,
    CreateHarshDecelerationEvent: 1750,
    CreateIdlingEvent: 0,
  },
  {
    driver: "c4e39006",
    company: "9d8616dd",
    driverName: "Henry",
    companyName: "Express",
    CreateIdlingEvent: 250,
    CreateSpeedingEvent: 2300,
    CreateHarshAccelerationEvent: 1988,
    CreateHarshDecelerationEvent: 1450,
  },
];

const map = new Map();
tempListData.forEach((o) =>
  map.set(
    o.driver,
    o.CreateIdlingEvent +
      o.CreateSpeedingEvent +
      o.CreateHarshAccelerationEvent +
      o.CreateHarshDecelerationEvent
  )
);

const result = [...tempListData].sort((a, b) => map.get(b.driver) - map.get(a.driver));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: it results ASC order of objects in array. I need DESC

Comment: @DeepKakkar Edited, Have a look